# OfficeToPDF not executing via shell_exec

Tags: php, cmd, localhost, ms-office, shell-exec

I am executing the command in by localhost on the  command line as:

```
OfficeToPDF.exe C:\wamp\www\editor\uploaded\uploaded_files_21_original\AffidavitinDIR-4.docx C:\wamp\www\editor\uploaded\uploaded_files_21_original\pdf\new2.pdf
```

This runs fine and provides the necessary result.

However, when I run it through php as:

```
shell_exec('OfficeToPDF.exe C:\wamp\www\editor\uploaded\uploaded_files_21_original\AffidavitinDIR-4.docx C:\wamp\www\editor\uploaded\uploaded_files_21_original\pdf\new2.pdf');
```

It does not execute and throws an error as:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Did not convert
```

I have been searching for all possible solutions but no luck.
I am running this on my windows machine - Localhost WAMP.

Any help please!

Comment: I'd bet on a permission issue. Launching your script as Administrator would tell us if that's the case?

Comment: How could I check it? Could you please help?

Comment: In start menu, search for "cmd", right click, select run as administrator, then run your php script in it.

Comment: I did as mentioned, I ran my php script(testing.php) through cmd as administrator, it does not

Comment: @HardikDave Can you find solution for this problem?